# How run Express Js/MongoDB in command line and close the terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I wanna know how can I run an express project but hide or close the terminal.

if I close the terminal my server fall, but I wanna hide it or something I'm doing a project in a local pc and me don't wanna that the user watches or close that and the app fall.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please elaborate and include some code. Get as far as you can!

Answer (score 0):

Use a process manager like [PM2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/) or [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever).

Forever example command: `forever start app.js`

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`nohup <command>`](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/unohup.htm)

`sudo nohup npm start`

A long version answer is to use [docker-compose with node js](https://blog.codeship.com/using-docker-compose-for-nodejs-development/) and run services which works in the background by running:
`docker-compose up -d <service_name>`